# Android Jsoup how to get this element

Tags: android, html, css, jsoup

Here is html:

```
<span id="priceblock_ourprice" class="a-size-medium a-color-price"><span class="currencyINR">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span> 69,000.00</span>
```

I want to get that `69,000.00` at the end I tried

```
.replace("<span class=\"currencyINR\">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>","")
```

But it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the above html you can use the `text` method:

```
String html = "<span id=\"priceblock_ourprice\" class=\"a-size-medium a-color-price\">"+
            "<span class=\"currencyINR\">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span> 69,000.00</span>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
String output;
output = doc.text();
System.out.println(output);
```

And the result:

> 69,000.00